# Can I query a nested document value in firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to do a search on the following data in firestore:
Collection->Document->{date{month:10,year:2017}}

```
var ref = db.collection(collection).doc(document)
ref.where('date.month', '==', 10).get().then(doc=>{
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
});
```

The above pseudo code does not work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are querying a document:

```
var ref = db.collection(collection).doc(document)
```

In stead you should be querying your [collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#simple_queries):

```
var ref = db.collection(collection)
```

Your query will pick up all documents, which meet "date.month==10" criteria among array of documents in your collection.

Also I think you have to change how you parse the data coming from .get() because it's going to be an array:

```
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
```

This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) should be also helpful to get the idea.