# Getting the data of nested collections

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am making my first angular/Firestore app and I am having some trouble understanding how to retrieve data in nested collections. My Firestore db path I want to read from is here:

```
/users/cl0Apvalb6c0w9hltQ8AOTF4go23/Fights/7WqHl5YUKPszkRELXEI2
```

So users is a collection, cl0Apvalb6c0w9hltQ8AOTF4go23 is an auto-id for a user, Fights is another collection, and 7WqHl5YUKPszkRELXEI2 is an auto id for an added fight (fights because this is an app to score fights in combat sports).

The fight itself (7WqHl5YUKPszkRELXEI2) is what contains the data like finalScore, redFighter, blueFighter, etc. that I want, How do I read this data?

I currently have an oAuth service that authenticates users and also declares the user observable.

```
export class AuthService {
user: Observable<User | null>;
fights: Observable<User | null>;

private userid: String 

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore, private router: Router)
 {
this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })     
);
}
```

Then in my HTML for the fights I want to display I have the data of the user document like user ID showing, so I know its currently reading the user document data at least.

```
 <!-- User logged in -->
<ng-template #authenticated>
<div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
<h3>Howdy, {{ user.displayName }}</h3>
<img  [src]="user.photoURL">
<p>UID: {{ user.uid }}</p>

<p>{{ user.testfield }}</p>
<p>{{user.what }}</p>
```

Im guessing in the constructor I also have to initialize fights, but I don't understand how to do so. I have tried various paths to get my data, but It never builds.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For you to query your nested collection, you should query the whole collection, checking for values that will bring only the documents from the subcollection.

Considering that this might sound confusing, I searched for some references for you to check and I could find a good tutorial that might help you with nested objects. I would recommend you to take a look at them, so you can get more content and examples on how to achieve it.

- [Firestore Tutorial Part 17 - NESTED OBJECTS - Android Studio Tutorial](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/cloud-firestore/part-17-nested-objects)
- [Can I query a nested document value in firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678037/can-i-query-a-nested-document-value-in-firestore)
- [Return nested collection from firestore as object for angularfire2 and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865124/return-nested-collection-from-firestore-as-object-for-angularfire2-and-firebase)

Let me know if the information helped you!